# Splitting a Grid in 4 Equal Portions

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

[image: to 4]

I was wondering if someone could provide a solution to this. Instructions are provided. Thank you.

Comment: Apparently you have to mention the exact source you found this (even though it's obviously not plagiarism since you're not claiming this as your own) before we can help you with it.

Comment: Can someone reopen this as I have solved it. 'Textbook' will probably do as a reference.

Comment: @JMP Um, no. I’d rather see puzzles go unanswered and end up deleted, than have us build a collection of other content creator’s puzzles without permission or attribution of their creators. Next time, pick something to spend effort solving that is not blatantly obviously taken without attribution, so your time won’t be wasted.